# What steps can you take ~ vs What steps you can take?

Tags: sentence-meaning, word-order, listening, word-stress

The speaker said on a video about relief tips:

> You then wanna formulate an action plan. 
>   **What steps can you take to start to address your worry**, 
>   and I guarantee you that as soon as you start to get into action around what you are worried about, you are gonna immediately start to feel better.

What I wonder is that the sentence '*What steps can you take to start to address your worry*' is correct.

I know the spoken English is not always as grammatically correct as the written English.

But in this case the speaker doesn't speak fast and doesn't seem to make a mistake.

Is it her mistake? or not?

You could watch [the part at 1:28](https://youtu.be/Sgh6rqq4TAs?t=1m28s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written every word correctly, good job! But the way you wrote it does sound strange. I listened to video clip and I would transcribe it like this:

> You then wanna formulate an action plan: what steps can you take to start to address your worry? And I guarantee you that as soon as you start to get into action around what you are worried about, you are gonna immediately start to feel better.

In other words, she is using the part

> what steps can you take to start to address your worry

to *clarify* what she means by *action plan*.

Another way to say this is

> What steps can you take to start to address your worry? Whatever those steps are, they will formulate your *action plan*.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

Use

> What steps can you take to address your worry...

to ask the question, and then answer the question with

> Steps you can take to address your worry are...